# Brain flour and fairies

Tags: humanity-has-declined

At the end of Jintai's specials we find out that Watashi seems to have permanently lost some of  her brain flour. The number on the fairy spoon was 322 at the beginning and it ended up being 280. Extreme reduction of that number makes Watashi smaller and more simple-minded. At a very low value she started looking like a fairy and her speech became very simplified.

[image]
[image] [image]

Does this mean that people can become fairies by reducing their brain flour levels? Can fairies become normal people if they eat some of those cookies made from the brain flour? Is this why they always crave sweets?

Also, Watashi looked like a very hard studying girl in the later episodes where her school life is shown. Did the loss of brain flour affected her intellectual capability enough to notice?

Comment: Watashi does not seems to be a fairy after being brain reduced : the fairies are known to be *at least as much intelligent as the regular humans*, while Watashi is way more stupid than an average human after reducing her *floor* level

Comment: Novel Vol9 have answer for that.